# Jest testing connected redux container component

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, redux, jestjs, connect

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as CommonActions from 'common/actions/common.actions';
import Activity from './activity.component';
const mapStateToProps = ({ common }) => ({common});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(
{
getNationalities: CommonActions.getNationalities,
},dispatch);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Activity);
```

How Can I test a container component like this which contains `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` ??

Comment: To test a redux store connected component, you need to wrap it in `Provider` using mock store. Alternatively, if you want to test unconnected `Activity` component, simply export it as well and test it like regular component. [More explanation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md#connected-components)

Answer (score 1):

[React-test-render](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) can test component, You have to import component that would include your `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`.

Example:

```
<YourComponentName
 common={jest.fn()}
 getNationalities={jest.fn()}
/>
```

Comment: I did like this but the problem is `bindActionCreators` these are not covered by the jest coverage ??